# How do I make a new CSS file for a new component in React JS?

Tags: css, reactjs, styles

Right now I made another component that is on a new window called `Blog.js`. In-line styling is convenient but eventually it will get crowded and annoying to edit. I want to make another stylesheet called `blog.css` but when I style in it, it styles `App.js` component instead. EDIT: just adding the rest of my code, I didn't want to add the `blog.module.css` because it only has a few styles (h2 with color and styling change).

**App.js:**

```
import React from "react"
import { Component } from "react"
import fbook from "./image/fbook.png"
import insta from "./image/insta.png"
import tweet from "./image/tweet.png"
import me from "./image/itsme.png"
import Blog from "./components/Blog.js"
import NewWindowComponent from "./NewWindowComponent"

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isNewWindow: false
    }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    
    
  }

  handleChange (event) {
    const {name, value} = event.target
      this.setState({name: value})
  }

  handleClick () {
    this.setState({
      isNewWindow: true
    })

  }



    render() {
      return (
    
      
        <body>
          <header>
            <h2>ALEX</h2>
              <div className="nav">
                  <a href="#">ALL</a>
                  <a href="#">TRAVEL</a>
                  <a href="#">LIFESTYLE</a>
                  <a href="#">MUSIC</a>
                  <a href="#">VIDEO</a>
              </div>

              <div className="search-box">
                <input type="text"
                className="search-bar"
                name="stuff"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                value={this.state.value}
                placeholder="Search" />

              </div>
          </header>

              <div id="background">
              <div className= "container">
                <h1>HI! I AM ALEX!</h1><hr/>
                <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                
                <NewWindowComponent
                  onClose={this.state.isNewWindow}>
                  <Blog /> //want to style this component
                </NewWindowComponent>

                <button onClick= {this.handleClick}>GO TO BLOG</button> 
                <img className= "my-pic" src={me} alt="pic of me"/> 
              </div>
              </div>

    

              <footer>
                <div className="icons">
                  <img className ="f-book" src={fbook} alt="Facebook"/>
                  <img className ="tweet" src={tweet} alt="Twitter"/>            
                  <img className ="insta" src={insta} alt="Instagram"/>
                </div>

              
                <p>© 2021, Designed by Alex </p>
              </footer>
            
        </body>
        
      
      )
    }
}

export default App
```

In the `blog.css` file I just wanted to style the h2 tag from `Blog.js` to make it red and italic but like I said before it styles the h2 tag in `App.js` even though I already have it styled in `index.css`.

**Blog.js:**

```
import React from "react"
import { Component } from "react";
import BlogCSS from '../components/Blog.module.css'; //clashes with App.js for some reason

class Blog extends Component {



render() {
    const myStyle = {
        fontStyle: 'italic',
        fontWeight: 'lighter',
        color: 'red',
        paddingLeft: 450,
        position: 'relative',
        fontSize: 50
    }

    const scrim = {
        backgroundColor: 'black'
    }

    const woah = {
        lineHeight: 1.5,
        fontSize: 20
    }

    return (

        
        <body>
            <header>
                <div style={scrim}className="background">
                <h2 style={myStyle}>Welcome to my Blog!</h2> //want to style this tag
                </div>
            </header>

            <div id="background">
            <div className= "container">
            <h2>About me I guess...</h2><hr/>
            <p style={woah}>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.           </p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    )
 }
}
export default Blog
```

**NewWindowComponent.js:**

```
import { Component } from "react"
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


class NewWindowComponent extends Component {

 containerEl = document.createElement('div');


 externalWindow = null;


componentDidMount() {
  
  this.externalWindow = window.open('', 'NewWindowComponent');

  
  if (this.externalWindow)
  {
    this.externalWindow.document.body.appendChild(this.containerEl);
    this.externalWindow.onunload = () => this.props.onClose();
  }
}

render() {
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(this.props.children, this.containerEl);
}
```

}

```
export default NewWindowComponent
```

**index.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css'
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);


reportWebVitals();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [css modules](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/)

1. Rename your css files with `filename.module.css`
2. Import it in the file you  want to use it `import styles from './filename.module.css';`
3. Use this in the element `<h2 class={style.yourClassName}>`

Share the complete code with css files if this doesn't help you

Comment: It isn't working after using your first step to change the css files to modules. It worked when I configured the `index.css` to `index.module.css` and tested in my `App.js`. For some reason when I do the same for `blog.module.css` and import in `Blog.js` it makes the h2 tag just vanish. Rest of my code is edited in above in question. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Also when I try to import the `blog.module.css` it immediately clashes with `App.js`